# Why I am getting a different answers when i am solving from 2d and 3d perspective??

Tags: geometry, volume

This a very simple question from surface area and volume so the question is:

A cube of maximum possible size is cut from a hemisphere of radius sqrt 6 cm. One identical cube is placed next to this cube to form a cuboid. Find the total surface area in cm² of the cuboid?

But when I am solving this question from 2d perspective I am getting 120 cm² as the answer but If you will try to solve this question from 3d perspective you will get 40 cm² as the final answer which is correct why these two answers different? And which one is correct?

[image: Visual representation of the 2d and 3d view]

Comment: I think you should include both the 3D version and the 2D version of how you solved the problem in your question, so that the reader can possibly see where you went wrong.

Comment: In the 2d version I have simply used the Pythagoras Theorem by assuming the side of the cube as "a" and here is my calculation  2a² =2root 6 ( since it is the  diameter of the hemisphere)

Comment: Please write down more of what you did. I understand you think it should be all clear to us from what you write, **but it isn't**. For a starter, what do you think is the side length of that initial cube cut from the hemisphere? I see nothing in the picture that even starts to look at this question.

Comment: I have assumed side of the cube as "a" initially

Comment: Please help me with this question

Comment: If $a^2=\sqrt{6}$ you don't get a cube that fits inside the hemisphere.

Comment: From what perspective you are solving??

Comment: Surya, you need to include the details of how you solved the problem, both ways - 2d and 3d, in the question, and not as a comment. Otherwise you will not get any help, since nobody has any idea what you're talking about. Think about it; you're asking "why do my two methods give me different answers", but have not described your two methods.

Comment: I think it is clear what you did.  The 2D version is obviously wrong, while the 3D version is the correct one.  With the cube base centered at the center of sphere, which is of radius $\sqrt{6}$, then if the side length of the cube (to be found) is $a$, it follows that $$ a^2 (3/2) = 6 $$.  Therefore $ a = 2 $, Hence the surface area area of the cuboid comprised of the two cubes is $2 ( 4 + 8 + 8) = 40 $.  which the answer that you got.  You can see that if you erect a cube with your 2D setup, the upper vertices will not lie on the surface of the hemisphere and that's why it is wrong.

Comment: Why the upper vertices will not lie on the surface of the hemisphere??